# why host server is showing more then one Process of index file?

Tags: wordpress, process

I am using WordPress blog on my website. The Web host is hostgator's server. The control Panel provided by hostgator showing more then one index file processes.  These processes become 10 to 20 sometimes and increase the CPU usage 20% to 45%. Hosts sends me alerts in this situation.

I am also using the plugins of wordpress `WP 3 TOTAL CACHE` and `WP CACHE`. normally 1500 to 2000 visitor visits my website at the same time.

Same problem occurring on my other website that also have wordpress blog but its on dedicated server of hostgator. 2500 to 3000 visitors remain on the site at the same time. How to recover this problem? I even upgraded the wordpress version but problem is still persisting. The server is apache 2.3.6. Processes list is showing something like... 

`4650    usr/bin/php/home/websitename/public_html/index.php   2.3%(CPU) 0.2%(MEM)
 4543    usr/bin/php/home/websitename/public_html/index.php   3.4%(CPU) 0.2%(MEM)
 4332    usr/bin/php/home/websitename/public_html/index.php   2.8%(CPU) 0.2%(MEM)`

Please help to recover from this situation. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with WordPress, but it pretty much looks like this is Apache reacting to the number of requests and scaling accordingly. Multiple concurrent requests have to be served in parallel, so Apache spawns processes to do so.

Comment: is it due to late response of script or long time processing?

Comment: Both and in general this is not something you want to avoid, as otherwise, the users would have to queue up to get served, which would increase latency.

Comment: Is it possible to be limited only for one process of index file? As much as processes produce these increase the CPU usage which 25% allowed of shared.

Comment: This is configurable in the Apache config. I recommend you reading through this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/worker.html

Comment: Also you may want to try actually increasing the number of processes, which may or may not decrease CPU load, as there will be less spawning of new processes.